# R how to increase distance between grids when using plot function?

Tags: r

I'm learning the Numerical Ecology with R. However, I found all my plots lacking the distance between bars or grids.
[myplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQA8i.png)
[textbook's plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMfOr.png)

```
spe.KM.cascade <-
cascadeKM(
    spe.norm2,
    inf.gr = 2,
    sup.gr = 10,
    iter = 100,
    criterion = "ssi"
)

dev.new(
    title = "CascadeKM",
    width = 10,
    height = 6,
    noRStudioGD = TRUE
)
plot(spe.KM.cascade, sortg = TRUE, border = 'white')
```

I want to know how to add white borders for every grid.

Comment: You need a) a data object to use for illustration and testing, and b) more explanation about what it is that is not being delivered. (I see no material difference in those two plots.)

Comment: Yeah, there is no difference between the results, but the plot. I want to know how to add white lines to divide the color blocks, so as to make the plot more visualized.

Comment: At the moment there is only the gridcol argument and the divisions will be the same color as grid that appears in the right-side plot, and they will be dashed thin lines. You need to edit the `plot.cascadeKM` function to replace the first `grid(...)`-call with one that accepts arguments for color, line type, and line width.

Comment: Got it. thank you. If I set `plot(...., ....., gridcol = "white")` then I can get the plot.

Comment: Maybe, although your control over the grid lines is pretty limited at the moment.